# How to access version of a Java application programmatically when running from an IDE?

Tags: java, versioning, jvm

As far as I understand, the best practice for programmatic access to the version of a Java application is to:

1. Specify version via build system (e.g. in Gradle).
2. Include the version string as a manifest attribute in the jar file.
3. Access it in application source code via [class `java.util.jar.Manifest`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/Manifest.html).

Is there a good way of doing the above, so that the version string is *meaningful* when running the application without the jar file? For example, when running it from an IDE, which just puts `build/classes` into classpath, without building the jar file.

One idea I have is to store the version string in a `version.properties` file. Build system will obviously have access to it. Application code will have access to it when launched from an IDE with correct working directory. Then, application code will be able to look up the version in the jar file and use `version.properties` as a fallback.

There is a problem with this approach though. The meaningfulness of the version string. Let me provide some context about version strings first.

It is a good practice to have differently looking version strings for "release" builds and "non-release" builds. Release builds are also called "clean" builds, and non-release builds are called "dirty" or "snapshot builds"—the exact naming doesn't matter in this case. What matters is the version string, which is read by a human. For example, a "release" build will have a version string something like `42.7`. And a dirty build after that, depending on the build system, will have something similar to one of these:

- `42.7-DIRTY`
- `42.8-DIRTY`
- `42.8-SNAPSHOT`
- etc

And every release build updates the version string stored in `version.properties` for persistence. There are also fancy variation of this theme, with inclusion of timestamps and/or commit hashes in the version string suffix, like `42.8-deadbeef-DIRTY` (see also [`git describe` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)), or calculating the version string from a Git tag. Regardless of the exact way of specifying a dirty build, this approach allows everyone involved in the development of the application can understand if some artifact is meant to be delivered/deployed/whatever or it is something from an intermediate state.

This approach breaks down when launching the application from an IDE. The manifest of the jar file can just not exist there and the fallback described above reads a version string from `version.properties`, but has no access to the build system logic of attaching a "dirty build" suffix.

A possible approach would be for the fallback to just duplicate the build system logic and attach the required suffix. And the fallback doesn't have to have the fancy commit hashes and timestamps—just `-DIRTY` could be enough. But duplication is not nice.

Another approach would be to borrow an idea from how C application versioning can be done. For example, in Git:

1. Version string is generated by [shell script `GIT-VERSION-GEN`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35151cf0720460a897cde9b8039af364743240e7/GIT-VERSION-GEN#L39).
2. [`Makefile` then passes `$GIT_VERSION` via `-D` option to the C compiler](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35151cf0720460a897cde9b8039af364743240e7/Makefile#L2227-L2228).
3. In application source code [`version.c` just accesses the macro `GIT_VERSION`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35151cf0720460a897cde9b8039af364743240e7/version.c#L5).

However, `javac` doesn't have exactly the same capability. [There is `-Akey[=value]` option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34788070/1083697), but writing an annotation processor for this seems like an overkill.

So, do we just give up and have some (albeit minor) duplication between build system and application source code? Or is there some other approach that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Duplication isn't a problem as long as it does not lead to duplicated maintenance issues or issues caused by forgetting to keep two places in the code in sync. Where in your scenario do you see that risk?

Comment: Out of curiosity what do you need the version for when running in an IDE?  Would "Development build" be sufficient?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen such information, when readily available in the UI (graphical or otherwise) can be used to double-check the version in workflows, where multiple release branches are maintained in parallel. Even when passing around snippets of application log around in instant messages between developers, such versioning information can be useful to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @andrybak do you want it baked into the code or determine at runtime by looking in .git?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen both approaches can be valid. My gut feeling is that the "baked into the code" is probably preferable. See also my comment under Basile Starynkevitch's answer.

Comment: I would consider writing a annotation for this then. Somebody probably already has 

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach is to generate some of your Java code (with tools like [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)) to contain version specific information.

Another approach might be to script your [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) editor to change some of your Java code (at file saving time) before compiling it.

Metaprogramming (i.e. ad-hoc code generation) is often useful.

You could use `git` hooks for that.

Comment: One of the approaches I've considered (haven't tried yet) is to generate a Java source file straight from Gradle. Such code could be placed directly in build script, or in `buildSrc`, or in a Gradle plugin (doesn't really matter).

It should play nicely with the Gradle's convention of using `build/generated` directory for generated source code. This convention is used, for example, by JavaCC.

Answer (score 0):

The `java` command, the command that launches java applications, has a set of standard options including the option of passing property value pairs to started application. The IDEs most probably offer the mean of customising the launch command thus including application specific property value pairs. The application's code could be enhanced to sequentially read the version from several locations, including the start options, until it finds a value.

That could be a possible solution although the application need to know its version seems strange in the way that same code when packaged in a version has an output for an input while packaged in a different version has a different output for same input.

Comment: "need to know " most likely means "capable of showing the user"